# convert the numbers to their names(1=one etc) with SED command

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I need to convert digits to their name ex: 1=one 2=two etc but I can only use **SED** command. Just the one-digit numbers should change.

```
sed 's/[1]/one/g; s/[2]/two/g; s/[3]/three/g; s/[4]/four/g; s/[5]/five/g; s/[6]/six/g; s/[7]/seven/g; s/[8]/eight/g; s/[9]/nine/g; s/[0]/zero/g'
```

Text:

Lo5se eyes get fat shew. Win4ter can indeed letter oppose way change te5nded now. So is imp6rove my charmed picture exposed adapt5ed demands. Received had en4d prod4uced prepared dive5rted strictly off man br55anched. Known 72ye money 6so large decay voice t6here to. Preserved be mr cordially incom88888mode as an. He 3doors qui03ck child an point at. Had sh2a9re vexed front least style off why him.

The result should be:

Lo**five**se eyes get fat shew. Win**four**ter can indeed letter oppose way change te**five**nded now. So is imp**six**rove my charmed picture exposed adapt**five**ed demands. Received had en**four**d prod**four**uced prepared dive**five**rted strictly off man br55anched. Known 72ye money **six**so large decay voice t**six**here to. Preserved be mr cordially incom88888mode as an. He **three**doors qui03ck child an point at. Had shtwoaninere vexed front least style off why him.

Comment: Why can you use only sed? And by the way, the single quotes are interpreted by the shell, which means you are already using another tool.

Comment: the command seems working

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: *can only use sed command*  -- Why?  Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I can use only Sed because the task of my homework ask for this :)

Comment: It's working but if the text cointains 11 or 22 etc it should't change. Just the single numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a sed that has `-E` to enable EREs and recognizes `\n` as meaning a newline (e.g. GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^0-9])([0-9])([^0-9]|$)/\1\n\2\n\3/g; s/\n1\n/one/g; s/\n2\n/two/g; s/\n3\n/three/g; s/\n4\n/four/g; s/\n5\n/five/g; s/\n6\n/six/g; s/\n7\n/seven/g; s/\n8\n/eight/g; s/\n9\n/nine/g; s/\n0\n/zero/g' file
Lofivese eyes get fat shew. Winfourter can indeed letter oppose way change tefivended now. So is impsixrove my charmed picture exposed adaptfiveed demands. Received had enfourd prodfouruced prepared divefiverted strictly off man br55anched. Known 72ye money sixso large decay voice tsixhere to. Preserved be mr cordially incommode as an. He threedoors qui03ck child an point at. Had shtwoa9re vexed front least style off why him.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+/\n&/g;s/\n(.[0-9])/\1/g;s/$/\n1one2two3three4four5five6six7seven8eight9nine0zero/;:a;s/\n(.)(.*\n.*\1([^0-9]+))/\3\2/;ta;P;d' file
```

Prepend a newline to each group of numbers.

Remove the prepended newline for numbers with more than two digits.

Append a newline and a lookup table to the end of the line.

Use a loop and pattern matching to replace each single digit with its literal, ensuring the lookup table is maintained.

Print the amended current line less the lookup table.